# How to create and reuse a module in XCode and Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, dry

Imagine I have this method to validate a given phone number:

```
func validatePhoneNumber(String: phoneNumber) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And I have project A in `/projects/A` and project B in `/projects/B`.

I don't want to copy/paste this function among projects. Rather, I want to apply DRY (do not repeat yourself) and reuse this function across these projects.

How can I do that in Swift and XCode? I have no clue to start.

Comment: FYI - this is not specific to Swift.

Comment: Why it's not related to Swift? After all, the language syntax and structure has an important role in reusing code snippets. For example, SASS doesn't let us use environment variables, or NPM doesn't let us define a parent `project.json`. Everything is related to applying DRY.

Comment: Here you go https://www.raywenderlich.com/192939/creating-a-framework-for-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to solve this problem is to create a Framework. Custom shared tools are stored a Framework like SharedTools.framework. A framework is it's own project (File > New > Project… then pick Cocoa Touch Framework or Cocoa Framework).

After you have the shared tools framework, it's only a matter of how you link them in to project A and project B.

- The shared tools project could be turned into a pod and use Cocoapods in Project A and Project B
- Project A and B could use Carthage to bring in the shared tools project
- Project A and B could be turned into Workspaces, and the shared tools project could be added as a required project

If you embed your project in a workspace there are a few ways you can do this.

- Have shared tools be side-by-side with project A and project B
- Have shared tools be a git submodule of A and B

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as an extension to String, so it would look like this

```
extension String {
  func isValidPhoneNumber() {
    return true // better logic here
  }
}
```

and you can use it like this `"5552324353".isValidPhoneNumber()`

Now you can either copy the .swift file between projects, or you can create a framework or a pod using cocoa pods.

Comment: The point is not about how to write this method. The point is about how to reuse it across projects, WITHOUT COPY/PASTING. That's the cheapest engineering. Yet you talked about creating a framework or a pod. Can you elaborate more.